# Create new table in excel from existing TABLE ,subject to pre-defined conditions

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a table where user can insert multiple rows over multiple columns where some data is string and some numeric. I want to create a button such that when the user clicks it, it will create a new table on the same excel sheet but with some of the rows combined based on predefined condition.
Eg. The table "pre defined condition" states that alpha and gamma are similar and so on(it can many rows like this which show the conditions to combine rows..condition will always pertain to second row of the user defined table i.e table 1)...Table 1 will be created by a different user and he can enter as many rows as he wishes to. So using these 2 tables (Table 1 & Pre defined condition tabel) I want to create a new table which has certain rows combined with stringfrom two rows separated using "/" and numbers added.
The structure will remain the same for all tables.

Edit:One value in column 2 will always have same value in column 1.Basically column 2 is a dependent list(on column 1 ). There can be many pre -defined conditions and not just limited to 2 . Usually there won't be any duplicate values in column 2,but in case there are I want to combine them in a row at click of the button.

```
Table 1
```

A   Alpha   100     1
B   Beta    200     2
C   Gamma   300     3
D   Kappa   400     4

Pre Defined Condition
Alpha   Gamma
Beta    Kappa

```
Desired Output
```

A/C Alpha/Gamma 400 4
B/D Beta/Kappa  600 6

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can create a button and assign a macro using the `Insert > Shapes`, then right click and assign macro. But I assume you question was more aimed at the coding rather than the button?

Comment: I have added a macro to create a new table which just copies the existing one. I am facing difficulty in combining the rows based on pre defined condition while creating the new table

Comment: the number of rows user adds in original table is a variable and there can be multiple set of conditions which i need to consider for combining rows.So i am not able to figure out how to achieve this

Comment: Can you add some examples of what these conditions might be? Also add the code you have so far. Best editing the question rather than posting in the comments section.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. For example, could the output be `B/D/G/K/P Beta/Kappa 1000 45`? (i.e., can one value of column 2 have different letters in column 1?) Also, there will be always two conditions only?

Comment: And one more: if there were duplicate values (two or more Kappa, for example), do you want this duplicates to be in the Output?

Comment: One value in column 2 will always have same value in column 1.Basically column 2 is a dependent list(on column 1 ). There can be many pre -defined conditions and not just limited to 2 . Usually there won't be any duplicate values in column 2,but in case there are I want to combine them in a row at click of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data starts in A2:D2 (A1:D1 left for titles), that you state two conditions (for example Alpha Gamma) in columns F and G (starting in the second row; first row left for titles), that there is a command button, and that the worksheet is named "Sheet1", the following code should do the trick.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lLastRowPDC As Integer
Dim lLastRowData As Integer
Dim sConditions As String
Dim sOrigin As String
Dim sColumnA As String
Dim sColumnB As String
Dim iColumnC As Integer
Dim iColumnD As Integer


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
lLastRowPDC = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6).End(xlDown).Row 'Rows with Conditions, starting in the second row
lLastRowData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'Rows with data, starting in the second row

For i = 2 To lLastRowPDC
    sConditions = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value 'create a string with the two conditions
    sColumnA = ""
    sColumnB = ""
    iColumnC = 0
    iColumnD = 0
    For j = 2 To lLastRowData
        sOrigin = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value
        If InStr(sConditions, sOrigin) > 0 Then
            If InStr(sColumnA, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value) = 0 Then
                sColumnA = sColumnA & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value & "/"
            End If
            If InStr(sColumnB, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                sColumnB = sColumnB & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 2).Value & "/"
            End If
            iColumnC = iColumnC + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3)
            iColumnD = iColumnD + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4)
        End If
    Next j
    sColumnA = Left(sColumnA, Len(sColumnA) - 1) 'remove last "/"
    sColumnB = Left(sColumnB, Len(sColumnB) - 1) 'remove last "/"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Value = sColumnA
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value = sColumnB
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value = iColumnC
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value = iColumnD
Next i

End Sub
```